# MVC SignalR keep increasing request count on each reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application which uses "SqlDependecy" and "SignalR" technologies to maintain real-time communication with the server based on database changes. It simply inspect a field value changes in specific database record and then display it on the browser.

The attempt works perfectly fine. But when I monitor the network requests through the browsers "Network" performance, the request count increases by 1 in every refresh of the page.

[image: Reference case screenshot]

As in the image.

1. Initial page load only make one request.
2. First refresh after the initial load and then db change will lead to make 2 requests.
3. Second refresh after the initial load and then db change will lead to make 3 requests.

so on...

The js code I tried is given below.

It seams as an problem to me. If this is a real problem, Any advice on this will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var jHub = $.connection.journeyHub;
        $.connection.hub.start();
        jHub.client.ListenChange = function () {
            getData();
        }
        jHub.client.ListenChange();
    });

    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetValue',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "pending") {
                    $("#box").css({ "background-color": "orange" });
                }
                else if (data == "deny") {
                    $("#box").css({ "background-color": "red" });
                }
                else if (data == "success") {
                    $("#box").css({ "background-color": "green" });
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: gray;"></div>
```

[Edit v1]
Here is my Controller where the event handler is located.

```
public class TravelController : Controller
{
    SqlConnection link = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["linkTraveller"].ConnectionString);

    // GET: Travel
    public ActionResult Listen()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetValue()
    {
        using (IDbConnection conn = link)
        {
            string query = @"SELECT [Status] FROM [dbo].[Journey] WHERE [Id]=1";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, link);
            SqlDependency sqlDep = new SqlDependency(command);
            sqlDep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler((sender, e) => sqlDep_OnChange(sender, e));
            conn.Open();
            string status = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    private void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        JourneyHub.Start();
    }
}
```

Here is the Hub

```
public class JourneyHub : Hub
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JourneyHub>();
        context.Clients.All.ListenChange();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I would say you are not decrementing your trigger handlers, sql dependency triggers only fire once and then they are gone, you have to remember the remove the event handler for it or they just keep adding but, but I will know for sure if you can post your sql dependency trigger code.

Here is a sample from something I did many years ago, but the idea is still the same.

```
try
        {
            using (
                var connection =
                    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id]
                                                                        ,[FName]
                                                                        ,[LName]
                                                                        ,[DOB]
                                                                        ,[Notes]
                                                                        ,[PendingReview] 
                                                       FROM [dbo].[Users]",
                    connection))
                {
                    // Make sure the command object does not already have
                    // a notification object associated with it.
                    command.Notification = null;

                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    command.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{   
    SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
    if (dependency != null) dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
    //Recall your SQLDependency setup method here.
    SetupDependency();
    JobHub.Show();
}
```

Comment: I'm also thinking of that, but I have no idea on where to put the decrement command for event handler. I've edited the case question with controller class and hub class.

Comment: Why are you starting a new hub everytime your SqlDependency triggers? Your hub should already be running.

Comment: Actually "Start" is just a custom made method that I'm using to expose a server-side function on client's context via the Hub. I came with this by referring many solutions on the internet. I'm still very confusing about the correct way of wiring-up the SignalR with SqlDependency. I'll study your suggestion and try it by the way...

Comment: The key to remember is to make sure that you only have one handler for each SQL Dependency, once the dependency is triggered, it will never trigger again, so you need to make sure the handler is removed.